# Hibernate. why does deleting a single child causes deletion of all child in unidirectional one-to-many association?

Tags: java, hibernate, associations, one-to-many

The third database command from bottom-up is DELETE FROM Person_Phone
WHERE  Person_id = 1
why delete person id instead of directly deleting phone id?
especially since that is what the java code explicitly does with person.getPhones().remove( phone1 )
. PS. I copied the code below from this link
http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/current/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#associations

```
//this is Java code
Person person = new Person();
Phone phone1 = new Phone( "123-456-7890" );
Phone phone2 = new Phone( "321-654-0987" );

person.getPhones().add( phone1 );
person.getPhones().add( phone2 );
entityManager.persist( person );
entityManager.flush();

person.getPhones().remove( phone1 );

//this is the database generated code
INSERT INTO Person
       ( id )
VALUES ( 1 )

INSERT INTO Phone
       ( number, id )
VALUES ( '123-456-7890', 2 )

INSERT INTO Phone
       ( number, id )
VALUES ( '321-654-0987', 3 )

INSERT INTO Person_Phone
       ( Person_id, phones_id )
VALUES ( 1, 2 )

INSERT INTO Person_Phone
       ( Person_id, phones_id )
VALUES ( 1, 3 )

DELETE FROM Person_Phone
WHERE  Person_id = 1

INSERT INTO Person_Phone
       ( Person_id, phones_id )
VALUES ( 1, 3 )

DELETE FROM Phone
WHERE  id = 2
```

Comment: can you post your entities?

Comment: @slimane this is an example from the official userguide. the pasted the link to this example in the my quesiton

Answer (score 1):

in the link you provided all the associations have a cascade property defined, which mean they will follow cascadetype value in it whenever an event is triggered(insert, update, delete ...), so as they all have set to cascadeType.All which means whenever a parent get removed (e.g insert) all his child will be removed (e.g insert) too,

here is a good [article](https://dzone.com/articles/beginner%E2%80%99s-guide-jpa-and) if you want to understand more about this behavior

Comment: @silmane I dont get why person.getPhones().remove( phone1 );
gets translated to DELETE FROM Person_Phone
WHERE  Person_id = 1. In this case we are deleting the child which is phone1. But the sql query deletes all parents row instead of child row. shouldn't the sql query be DELETE FROM Person_Phone
WHERE  Phone_id = 2?